# Relative Risk and Confidence Interval from GLM

Tags: r, confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, relative-risk

We're trying to replicate a study by [MacInnis et al. (2016)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4790628/) using R. The goal is to derive relative risks (RR) and confidence intervals (CI) from a GLM with a binary outcome and several categorical and continuous predictors. The more I read about the possible ways to do this, the more confused I get. Right now, I have the following questions:

1. Given the limitations that logit, poisson or log-bin have to derive RR CI ([Localio et al. 2006](http://www.jclinepi.com/article/S0895-4356(06)00469-0/fulltext)), is there a favorable model to go for in most cases or is the decision always dependent on the data, i.e. how rare the outcome events are, the sample size etc.? For example, do we have to apply several models for different outcomes with variable prevalences?
2. Is there an R package that fits well to this problem, i.e. calculating adjusted RRs and CIs in large cohort studies. I've found the prLogistic package, but I find it difficult to judge if the underlying statistic is appropriate.
3. Is there irrespective of the stat platform any walkthrough or tutorial for this exact same problem that would allow me to reproduce the steps using R?